# Java inheritance method call

Tags: java

I have a interesting scenario that.

```
public class Base {

    public void hello(){
        this.say();
        System.out.println("hello-Base");
    }

    protected void say(){
        System.out.println("say-Base");
    }
}



public class Derived extends Base {

    public Derived(){
        super.hello();      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived d = new Derived();      
    }

    public void say(){
        System.out.println("say-Derived");
    }

}
```

The output given is that:

```
say-Derived
hello-Base
```

I was expecting that when super.hello() method was invoked, say() method of Base classes was invoked rather than say()method of Derived class.

What is the reason behind this logic?

Comment: `this` is a `Derived`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Super.hello() calls this.say() which(this) refer to the current object i.e. derived** so it calls the say method of derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` **-- points to --->** Instance of Type `Derived`

So due to overriding `Derived` class method is called.

Answer (score 1):

super.hello(); is raised from Derived constructor i.e. object of derived class. Which in turns calls this.say() i.e. derived.say(). So that's why the output is so.